# IE Protractor Test issues with IEDriverServer not being present

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, protractor, driver, iedriverserver

I'm trying to get IE to work with protractor. I suspect the issue is with the driver. When I enter in `Webdriver-manager status`, I get the below status.

```
[13:05:13] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.141.59 [last]
[13:05:13] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.46 [last]
[13:05:13] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.24.0 [last]
[13:05:13] I/status - IEDriverServer is not present
[13:05:13] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[13:05:13] I/status - appium is not present
```

Even when I do `npm install ie` and then do the `webdriver-manager status`, I get the same message of the IE driver not being present. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i needed to install it globally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it globally.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.